# Use result from query to add another column to the results SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

These are the relevant tables:

- **userInfo**

  - *username*
  - *profileImgUrl*
- **follows**

  - *follower*
  - *following*

In the **follows** table the follower and the following attributes are usernames. Where the follower follows the following.

I would like to add another column where it states if the person requesting the query, in this case, 'admin', follows the selected u.username.

Current query:

```
SELECT u.username, u.profileImgUrl 
FROM userInfo u, follows f WHERE f.following = 'admin'
AND f.follower = u.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select u.*,
       ( exists (select 1 from follows f where f.follower = u.username and f.following = 'admin')
       ) as flag
from userInfo u;
```

MySQL supports a "boolean" data type that can look a lot like a number, so this returns "1" if a row exists in `followers` and `0` if it does not.

Comment: I have added this part at the end:  WHERE f.following = 'admin'
AND f.follower = u.username
and it works fine. Thank you!